# Deleting a row from a DataFrame without referring to the index set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'col2': [-3, 4, 5, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4], 'col3': ['a','a','b', 'a','c','a','a','a','a','a']})
```

I want to drop the rows which do not have 'a' in the third column. In this case, the third and fifth rows are to be dropped and I can do it with the following command

```
df.drop([2,4])
```

Is there a way to do it without referring to the index set [2,4] and directly involving 'col3' and 'a'?

I have a big dataset, and I only need one value, say 'a', in the last columns and drop all the rows which do not have 'a' in the last column.

Comment: looks like you need boolean indexing : ``df.loc[df.col3.eq('a')]``

Comment: df.query('col3 == "a"')